# How can I overlay the text and pager inside the image?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am adding slider image on my app but I cannot overlay the text inside the image.

```
  <ion-slides   *ngIf="getData.length>0" autoplay="2700" speed="300" class="slideroption" pager="true" loop="true">[![enter image description here][1]][1]
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of getData" (click)="openItem(item)"> 
          <img src="{{item.jetpack_featured_media_url}}" class="new-collection" /> 
          <h4  [innerHTML]="item.title.rendered"></h4>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nx8nbk

Comment: I have a image in ionic card but I don't know how can I put text in the middle of my image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below CSS on `h4` tag.

```
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h4 class="centered"  [innerHTML]="item.title.rendered"></h4>
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-m4h968?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: but my pager icon still in same position.